# How to Use postMessage on iFrame

Tags: javascript, node.js, iframe, csrf, same-origin-policy

I have 2 nodeJS applications with the following domains:

- localhost:8000
- localhost:3000

In localhost:3000, I have a textarea, and a submit button.

I want to post the contents of the textarea (using postMessage) to a localhost:8000/(some_id), and display the contents on the localhost:8000 page.

Then, I want to show an iFrame of the localhost:8000/(some_id) in the localhost:3000 page.

I am having a lot of trouble accomplishing this. I must accomplish it in this way using postMessage().

PS: I know it is probably best to avoid iFrames, however for the purpose of my application, this is necessary to use.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Whatever you `postMessage` on one side will be sent to the `message` listener on the other side.

```
// in the parent document
iframeElement.contentWindow.postMessage('hi!');
```

```
// in the iframe
window.addEventListener('message', ({ data }) => {
  console.log('i got some data!', data); // i got some data! hi!
});
```

You can also go the other way, and use `window.parent.postMessage()` in the iframe source and listen for it with `window.addEventListener('message', ...)` in parent document.