# Access Chrome local storage from specific domain in Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, local-storage

My Chrome Extension has a background script as well as a content script. The content script redirects to a new page ([www.nike.com](http://www.nike.com)). The page adds 3 domains and a some data to the local storage. I want to access one of the domains storage.

I tried to use the Chrome.storage API inside my background script and in my content script, but I always receive an empty object.

I also added the onChange event listener, but this wasn't successful too. It seems that the local storage is empty. Is it even possible to access exactly this storage?

[image]

Comment: `wndow.localStorage` is a different storage not related to `chrome.storage`. Devtools shows only the former in Chrome. You need to use a content script to read the site's `localStorage`.

Comment: I used chrome.storage.local, which should be able to find the keys I am searching for. I implemented it into the content script as you told, but it did not work. Instead it's empty, even with the onChange listener in the content script.

Comment: Ah, chrome.storage.local is not equal to window.localStorage. And in my extension I have to use window.localStorage to get the data I need?

Comment: I believe my comment above already contains an answer.

Answer (score -1):

Local storage is a property of the domain, and since both these domains are different you won't be able to access it.

Check this out: [Accessing iframe's parent localstorage variable from iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39322475/accessing-iframes-parent-localstorage-variable-from-iframe)